# How to dynamically add extra requests to a Guzzle Pool?

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle (http://guzzlephp.org) to GET a large number of urls (~300k) . The urls are retrieved from an Elastic Search instance, and I would like to keep adding urls to a Pool so the Pool stays rather small instead of adding them all at once.

Is this possible? I looked at the Pool.php, but did not find a way to do this. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

Use while and generator (yield).

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$client = new Client();

$requests = function () {
  $uris = ['http://base_url'];
  $visited_uris = []; // maybe database instead of array

  while(len($uris)>0)
    yield new Request('GET', array_pop($uris));
  }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(), [
  'concurrency' => 5,
  'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
    $new_uri = get_new_uri(); // implement function to get new $uri
    if(in_array($new_uri, $visited_uris)) {
      array_push($uris, $uri);
    }

    array_push($visited_uris, $uri);
  }
]);

$promise = $pool->promise();
$promise->wait();
```